# NET Core 3.1 MVC Input Validation does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In some viewmodel classes the [Required] attributes works as expected. When submitting the form, the error spans show an error message underneath the fields and the form is not submitted if the required fields do not meet the annotation requirements.

But in the example shared below, the form is submitted even if the required fields are empty (such as CompanyName) and I haven't figured out why, some help would be appreciated please.

Startup.cs

```
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); // throw a classic error page is evironment is development
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");          
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
}
...
```

EditCompanyVM.

```
public class EditCompanyVM
    {
        public EditCompanyVM()
        {
            Contact = new Contact();
            Locations = new List<CompanyLocation>();
        }

        public int CompanyID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company name is required.")]
        public string  CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company description is required.")]
        public string CompanyDescription { get; set; }

        [Url]
        public string CompanyWebsite { get; set; }

        public Contact Contact { get; set; }

        public List<CompanyLocation> Locations { get; set; }

    }
```

EditCompany.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.Models.ViewModels.EditCompanyVM


@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Company";
}

<div class="col-md-8">

    <h4 style="margin:0 0 30px 0;">Edit Company</h4>

    <form method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CompanyID" class="control-label">Company ID</label>
            <input asp-for="CompanyID" disabled class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CompanyID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CompanyName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" type="text" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CompanyName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CompanyDescription" class="control-label">Company Description</label>
            <input asp-for="CompanyDescription" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CompanyDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CompanyWebsite" class="control-label">Company Website</label>
            <input asp-for="CompanyWebsite" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CompanyWebsite" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="contactSection">
            <h4 style="margin:0 0 20px 0;">Contact Section</h4>

            @if (Model.Contact != null)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Contact.ContactID" class="control-label">Contact ID</label>
                    <input asp-for="Contact.ContactID" disabled class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contact.ContactID" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contact.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Contact.PhoneNumber" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
                    <input asp-for="Contact.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Contact.Email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input asp-for="Contact.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contact.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <a asp-action="AddContact" asp-route-userId="@Model.CompanyID" style="width:auto" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                    Add Contact
                </a>
            }


        </div>


        <div id="locationsSection">
            <h4 style="margin:20px 0 20px 0;">Company Locations</h4>

            @if (Model.Locations.Any())
            {
                int counter = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Locations.Count; i++)
                {
                    <h3>Location @counter</h3>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Street" class="control-label">Street</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Street" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].Street" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].City" class="control-label">City</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].City" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].City" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Province" class="control-label">Province</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Province" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].Province" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Country" class="control-label">Country</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Country" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].Country" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].ZipCode" class="control-label">ZipCode</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].ZipCode" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].PhoneNumber" class="control-label">Location Phonenumber</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Email" class="control-label">Branch Email</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Manager" class="control-label">Manager Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Locations[i].Manager" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Locations[i].Manager" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else
            {

            <a asp-action="AddLocation" asp-route-id="@Model.CompanyID" style="width:auto;" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                Add Location
            </a>
        </div>
          }




        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:80px;">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
                <a asp-action="ListCompanies" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>


</div>
```

CompanyController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditCompany (EditCompanyVM model)
    {
        // model is submitted with null fields, even though warnings should trigger in the view 
        // by asp-validation-for
        return RedirectToAction("ListCompanies");
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?
P.S on the client you use unobtrusive validation to validate forms and on the server side you use the`model state` like: 
`If(!ModelState.IsValid){ return View(); }`

Comment: @HMZ yes, just did, nothing shows up. Just submits an empty model to the controller.

Comment: @HMZ also when I edit a "Company" I erase the existing name then try to submit, dont know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: @HMZ yes I usually use the ModelState.IsValid..that part works, the ModeState.IsValid is false indeed. Just not the required fields error messges, they dont show up, but they work fine for a db table model.... for example if I used Company model class, instead of EditCompanyVM

Comment: And for your client side validation use [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) if you aren't.
Add this library and the error messages will appear in your views.

Comment: @HMZ didnt know about the jQuery Unobtrusive Validation but will check the docs. Thanks for that,

Comment: Just add it, you don't have to do anything. Its designed for asp.net core it will pickup on your server side validation attributes by it self.

Comment: @HMZ IIRC, the way to correctly return the invalid state would be with `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(model); }` -> the received model returned to the View being the important bit

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You're right, my bad.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(model); }` this is for server side validation checking. It has nothing to do with client side validation checking

Comment: @RazvanEmil check the generated html for `data-val-required`

Comment: @RazvanEmil also check if you have included 3 js libraries `jquery`, `jquery.validate`, `jquery.validation.unobtrusive`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I didn't claim otherwise. I was merely pointing out that just using `return View();` wouldn't generate the validation errors

Comment: The request will not be sent at all if there is validation error and will be stopped at client side only. As it's not stopping so issue is either not loading the unobtrusive javascript files or may be missing data-* attributes. so server side validation  `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(model); }` can be next concern, but not immediate.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you were right, I am not returning the model. How silly of me, cant believe it.  It works when returning the model. RajdeepDebnath thanks for your suggestions, camilo was right.

Comment: @RazvanEmil only returning the model made it work cannot happen. You definitely don't need to return the model to make asp.net client side validation work with data annotation on model. This is incorrect learning. When you return the model it also includes server side validation error as well, but without returning that you can do client side validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been a lot of discussion in the comments, so I'd like to clear some things up.

Client-side validation happens in a user's browser, and requires scripts to take place. If a form is not valid, the script can prevent the form from being submitted, and display error messages for a user to correct. This is an enhancement for users, and servers, as it stops the majority of invalid requests being sent to the server, when they could be handled by the user in their browser.

Server-side validation takes place in addition to client-side validation - client-side validation is the optional extra, not the other way around, because users cannot be trusted to be non-malicious. Server-side validation within ASP.NET Core takes place using a combination of data annotations, and validators, that culminate in `ModelState`. Server-side validation will not prevent a form from being submitted in a user's browser, but *can* still send errors back to the browser via `ModelState` and returning your current model:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditCompany(EditCompanyVM model)
{
    // This property indicates if the model's data, 
    // based on the data annotations it's
    // decorated with, is valid.
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Returning the same instance of the model back
        // to the view causes Razor to use the `ModelState`'s
        // data to render errors via `asp-validation-for`.
        return View(model);
    }

    // If no errors, redirect.
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now, if your question is why you're able to submit the form without validation first taking place, and subsequently preventing invalid data from being submitted, this is all because of the client-side validation - it has nothing to do with your controller at all; this is all down to what's going on in your view.

If you take a look in your `~Views/Shared` folder, you should see a view called `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`. The default views prefixed with a `_` are intended to be used as partial views, although this is a convention you don't have to follow with your own views. If you open it up, you'll see it contains the following:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

These are scripts for client-side validation, but they're not included by default. Therefore, to fix your problem, simply add the following at the bottom of your `EditCompany.cshtml` view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

This will now render those scripts to the browser, loading client-side validation. Trying to submit your form now will trigger client-side validation, *without* hitting the server if the data is invalid.

Comment: Amazing explanation @JohnH. That was what I was mentioning in the comment that unobtrusive javascripts are not being loaded and client side validation has nothing to do with modelstate.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the feedback. I've made an edit to change that.